# OpenOffice draw:enhanced-geometry parsing

Tags: javascript, libreoffice

I'm writing OOo converter and stuck at `draw:enhanced-geometry` > `draw:enhanced-path` with `draw:equation`, cannot find any solution or wide documentation about this section. At least mb someone can recommend how to evaluate it?

Sample code that i stuck on it (draws balloon):

```
                        "draw:enhanced-geometry": [{
                            "$": {
                                "svg:viewBox": "0 0 21600 21600",
                                "draw:text-areas": "800 800 20800 20800",
                                "draw:type": "round-rectangular-callout",
                                "draw:modifiers": "3289.58566629339 27438.6415787058",
                                "draw:enhanced-path": "M 3590 0 X 0 3590 L ?f2 ?f3 0 8970 0 12630 ?f4 ?f5 0 18010 Y 3590 21600 L ?f6 ?f7 8970 21600 12630 21600 ?f8 ?f9 18010 21600 X 21600 18010 L ?f10 ?f11 21600 12630 21600 8970 ?f12 ?f13 21600 3590 Y 18010 0 L ?f14 ?f15 12630 0 8970 0 ?f16 ?f17 Z N"
                            },
                            "draw:equation": [{
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f0",
                                    "draw:formula": "$0 -10800"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f1",
                                    "draw:formula": "$1 -10800"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f2",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f18 ,$0 ,0)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f3",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f18 ,$1 ,6280)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f4",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f23 ,$0 ,0)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f5",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f23 ,$1 ,15320)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f6",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f26 ,$0 ,6280)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f7",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f26 ,$1 ,21600)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f8",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f29 ,$0 ,15320)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f9",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f29 ,$1 ,21600)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f10",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f32 ,$0 ,21600)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f11",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f32 ,$1 ,15320)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f12",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f34 ,$0 ,21600)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f13",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f34 ,$1 ,6280)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f14",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f36 ,$0 ,15320)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f15",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f36 ,$1 ,0)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f16",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f38 ,$0 ,6280)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f17",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f38 ,$1 ,0)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f18",
                                    "draw:formula": "if($0 ,-1,?f19 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f19",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,-1,?f22 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f20",
                                    "draw:formula": "abs(?f0 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f21",
                                    "draw:formula": "abs(?f1 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f22",
                                    "draw:formula": "?f20 -?f21 "
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f23",
                                    "draw:formula": "if($0 ,-1,?f24 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f24",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,?f22 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f25",
                                    "draw:formula": "$1 -21600"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f26",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f25 ,?f27 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f27",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,-1,?f28 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f28",
                                    "draw:formula": "?f21 -?f20 "
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f29",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f25 ,?f30 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f30",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,?f28 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f31",
                                    "draw:formula": "$0 -21600"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f32",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f31 ,?f33 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f33",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,?f22 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f34",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f31 ,?f35 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f35",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,-1,?f22 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f36",
                                    "draw:formula": "if($1 ,-1,?f37 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f37",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,?f28 ,-1)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f38",
                                    "draw:formula": "if($1 ,-1,?f39 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f39",
                                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,-1,?f28 )"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f40",
                                    "draw:formula": "$0 "
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:name": "f41",
                                    "draw:formula": "$1 "
                                }
                            }],
                            "draw:handle": [{
                                "$": {
                                    "draw:handle-position": "$0 $1"
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**draw:enhanced-path** could be placed inside the svg path element. You will got something like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 21600 21600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path d="M 3590 0 X 0 3590 L ?f2 ?f3 0 8970 0 12630 ?f4 ?f5 0 18010 Y 3590 21600 L ?f6 ?f7 8970 21600 12630 21600 ?f8 ?f9 18010 21600 X 21600 18010 L ?f10 ?f11 21600 12630 21600 8970 ?f12 ?f13 21600 3590 Y 18010 0 L ?f14 ?f15 12630 0 8970 0 ?f16 ?f17 Z N"/>
</svg>
```

Then you should expand all variables (like ?f2) and argumements (like $0). Check the snippen below for the example. However, I don't know what to do with the 'X' and 'Y' literals in path. I didn't found them in this doc http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html .

```js
function extractPath(dataObj, args) {
 // collect variables
 var variableSource = dataObj['draw:enhanced-geometry'][0]['draw:equation'];
 var variables = {};
 for (var i = 0; i < variableSource.length; i++) {
  var name = variableSource[i]['$']['draw:name'];
  var value = variableSource[i]['$']['draw:formula'];
  variables[name] = value;
 }
 
 var evaluateVariable = function(name) {
  var value = evaluateExpression(variables[name]);
  return value; 
 } 

 var evaluateExpression = function(expr) {
  if (expr.match('if\\(([^),]+),([^),]+),([^),]+)\\)')) {
   var literals = expr.match('if\\(([^),]+),([^),]+),([^),]+)\\)').slice(1);
   if (evaluateLiteral(literals[0]) > 0) {
    return evaluateLiteral(literals[1]);
   }
   else {
    return evaluateLiteral(literals[2]);
   }
  }
  else if (expr.match('abs\\(([^)]+)\\)')) {
   var literals = expr.match('abs\\(([^)]+)\\)').slice(1);
   return Math.abs(evaluateLiteral(literals[0]));
  }
  else if (expr.match('([^()-\\s]+[\\s]?)-([^()-\\s]+[\\s]?)')) {
   var literals = expr.match('([^()-\\s]+[\\s]?)-([^()-\\s]+[\\s]?)').slice(1);
   return evaluateLiteral(literals[0]) - evaluateLiteral(literals[1]);
  }
 }  

 var evaluateLiteral = function(literal) {
  if (literal.match('^\\?f[\\d]+[\\s]*$')) {
   return evaluateVariable(literal.match('f[\\d]+')[0].trim());
  }
  else if (literal.match('^\\$[\\d]+[\\s]*$')) {
   return args[literal.match('[\\d]+')[0].trim()];
  }
  else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(literal.trim()))) {
   return parseFloat(literal.trim());
  }
  console.error("couldn't evaluate literal '" + literal + "'");
  return literal;
 } 

 var pathSource = dataObj['draw:enhanced-geometry'][0]['$']['draw:enhanced-path'];
 
 var loopLimit = 1000; // to avoid infinite loop
 var path = pathSource;
 while (path.match('\\?f[\\d]+')) {
  var variable = path.match('\\?f[\\d]+')[0].slice(1);
  var calculatedValue = evaluateVariable(variable);
  path = path.replace('?' + variable, calculatedValue);
  if (loopLimit-- < 0) {
   console.error('loopLimit is out, looks like you have got an infinite loop here');
  }
 }
    alert('path = "' + path + '"');
 return path;
}

function onLoad() {
 var jsonObj = '{"draw:enhanced-geometry": [{\
            "$": {\
                "svg:viewBox": "0 0 21600 21600",\
                "draw:text-areas": "800 800 20800 20800",\
                "draw:type": "round-rectangular-callout",\
                "draw:modifiers": "3289.58566629339 27438.6415787058",\
                "draw:enhanced-path": "M 3590 0 X 0 3590 L ?f2 ?f3 0 8970 0 12630 ?f4 ?f5 0 18010 Y 3590 21600 L ?f6 ?f7 8970 21600 12630 21600 ?f8 ?f9 18010 21600 X 21600 18010 L ?f10 ?f11 21600 12630 21600 8970 ?f12 ?f13 21600 3590 Y 18010 0 L ?f14 ?f15 12630 0 8970 0 ?f16 ?f17 Z N"\
            },\
            "draw:equation": [{\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f0",\
                    "draw:formula": "$0 -10800"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f1",\
                    "draw:formula": "$1 -10800"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f2",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f18 ,$0 ,0)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f3",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f18 ,$1 ,6280)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f4",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f23 ,$0 ,0)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f5",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f23 ,$1 ,15320)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f6",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f26 ,$0 ,6280)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f7",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f26 ,$1 ,21600)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f8",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f29 ,$0 ,15320)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f9",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f29 ,$1 ,21600)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f10",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f32 ,$0 ,21600)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f11",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f32 ,$1 ,15320)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f12",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f34 ,$0 ,21600)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f13",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f34 ,$1 ,6280)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f14",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f36 ,$0 ,15320)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f15",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f36 ,$1 ,0)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f16",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f38 ,$0 ,6280)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f17",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f38 ,$1 ,0)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f18",\
                    "draw:formula": "if($0 ,-1,?f19 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f19",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,-1,?f22 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f20",\
                    "draw:formula": "abs(?f0 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f21",\
                    "draw:formula": "abs(?f1 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f22",\
                    "draw:formula": "?f20 -?f21 "\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f23",\
                    "draw:formula": "if($0 ,-1,?f24 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f24",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,?f22 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f25",\
                    "draw:formula": "$1 -21600"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f26",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f25 ,?f27 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f27",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,-1,?f28 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f28",\
                    "draw:formula": "?f21 -?f20 "\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f29",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f25 ,?f30 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f30",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,?f28 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f31",\
                    "draw:formula": "$0 -21600"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f32",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f31 ,?f33 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f33",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,?f22 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f34",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f31 ,?f35 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f35",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f1 ,-1,?f22 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f36",\
                    "draw:formula": "if($1 ,-1,?f37 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f37",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,?f28 ,-1)"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f38",\
                    "draw:formula": "if($1 ,-1,?f39 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f39",\
                    "draw:formula": "if(?f0 ,-1,?f28 )"\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f40",\
                    "draw:formula": "$0 "\
                }\
            },\
            {\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:name": "f41",\
                    "draw:formula": "$1 "\
                }\
            }],\
            "draw:handle": [{\
                "$": {\
                    "draw:handle-position": "$0 $1"\
                }\
            }]\
        }]}';
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
    console.log(obj);

    var svgTag = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    console.log(svgTag);
    var viewBox = document.createAttribute('viewBox');
    viewBox.value = obj['draw:enhanced-geometry'][0]['$']['svg:viewBox'];
    svgTag.setAttributeNode(viewBox);

    var svgPathTag = document.createElement('path');
    var stroke = document.createAttribute('stroke');
    stroke.value = 'black';
    svgPathTag.setAttributeNode(stroke);
    var strokeWidth = document.createAttribute('stroke-width');
    strokeWidth.value = '3';
    svgPathTag.setAttributeNode(strokeWidth);
    var pathData = document.createAttribute('d');
    pathData.value = extractPath(obj, [1, 2]);
    svgPathTag.setAttributeNode(pathData);
    svgTag.appendChild(svgPathTag);
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad()">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"/>
</body>
```

I hope this answer will be helpful.